# SemanticZoom without GridView

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, semantic-zoom

I'd like to know, how I can implement my own SemanticZoom WITHOUT GridView control.

I have my own custom controls on the mainpage but a structure similar to a grouped GridView and I want to open details after the user makes a zoom-gesture on a group.

But it seems that the SemanticZoom control only works together with the GridView.

Any ideas?

cheers, Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controls contained inside the SemanticZoom control can be any control that implements the **ISemanticZoomInformation** interface - [ISemanticZoomInformation interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.isemanticzoominformation.aspx)

Simple example at [Semantic Zoom only supports GridView and ListView?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/going_metro/archive/2012/07/18/semantic-zoom-only-supports-gridview-and-listview.aspx)